# How to data in SQL Server from excel file with same column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need to import an excel file to SQL Server in multiples tables.

[image: Excel information example]

I want to insert the column `PARTNUMBER`, and `PART_DESCRIPTION`,
in a table called `PartNumbers`, so that's ok, I can do it.

But I don't know how to can I do dynamically, or how to insert the another columns `("SUB_ITEM1", "SUB_ITEM2", "SUB_ITEM3")`, because,
I want to insert for example, in a table called `Results`,
I want to insert in each row information like this:

```
SUB_ITEM    PASS   FAILED    IdPartNumber
Test          1       0       1
Test2         0       1       1
Test3         0       0       1
Test          0       1       2
Test2         1       0       2
Test3         1       1       2
```

How can I do it?, I'm using `OPEN ROWSET`, To read the excel file from SQL Server,
And if I only put a query like `("SELECT * FROM MyExcelSheet")`, it gonna give me error because
I have repeated columns `("PASS", and "FAILED")`.

Comment: Just insert them into columns "PASS1" "PASS2" etc.

Comment: Do it multiple insert statements i.e. first insert will insert `PARTNUMBER`and description, second insert will insert `SUB_ITEM1`, third insert - `SUB_ITEM2`etc.